# How to print click events in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, events, button, onclick

```
 <body>

  <button id ="b1">BUTTON</button>
  </br>
  <p id="text"> </p> 

  <script type="text/javascript">

   document.getElementById("b1").onmouseout = reset_button;
   document.getElementById("b1").onmousedown = mousedown_button;
   document.getElementById("b1").onmouseover = mouse_over;
   document.getElementById("b1").onmousemove = mouse_move;
   document.getElementById("b1").onclick = click_button;


   function reset_button() {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = 
    "mouseout";
   }
   function mousedown_button() {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = 
   "mousedown";
   }
   function click_button() {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = 
    "click";
   }
   function mouse_over() {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML =
    "mouseover";
   }
   function mouse_move() {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML =
    "mousemove";
   }

   </script>
  </body>
```

I want to print mouseout, mousedown, mouseover, mousemove and onlick when I press button. However, this code I made only prints mouseover, mousedown and mouseout. Can someone explain which part is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Try using `console.log('name')` instead of innerHTML as it is probably being called just gets override but something else. Console.log will append to the console so you will be able to see everything.

Comment: Put console.log('your event'); in your function

Comment: Thank you for your example. I am happy to see the ultimate demonstration of necessary separation of JS from HTML.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about console method. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text gets overwritten, see console output here:

**Update: Simplified code**

(kudos to Little Alien)

```js
['mouseout', 'mousedown', 'mouseover', 'mousemove', 'click'].forEach(
    ev_name =>b1.addEventListener(ev_name, e => console.log(ev_name)))
```

```html
<button id="b1">BUTTON</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concise version of what you tried to do. Just 3 lines of code.

```js
['mouseout', 'mousedown', 'mouseover', 'mousemove', 'click'].forEach(
    ev_name =>b1.addEventListener(ev_name, e => b1.innerHTML += " " + ev_name))
```

```html
<button id="b1">click me</button>
```

Comment: I like your approach and updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

mousemove and mouseover events are interfering with each other try removing mousemove event.

```
  <body>

  <button id ="b1">BUTTON</button>
  </br>
  <p id="text"> </p> 

  <script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("b1").onclick = click_button;
   document.getElementById("b1").onmouseout = reset_button;
   document.getElementById("b1").onmousedown = mousedown_button;
   document.getElementById("b1").onmouseover = mouse_over;




   function reset_button() {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = 
    "mouseout";
   }
   function mousedown_button() {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = 
   "mousedown";
   }
   function click_button() {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = 
    "click";
   }
   function mouse_over() {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML =
    "mouseover";
   }

   </script>
  </body>
```